# I already have SFML includes folder but i can't import it in my project

Tags: c++, sfml

I download SFML 2.5.1, I put it in same folder as my code. But not working! 
My code:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

It's return an error:

```
sfml.cpp:1:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
```

I also try `<path/to/SMFL/...>` but not working too

Please help me

Comment: What matters is which command you use to compile the code

Comment: g++ sfml.cpp -o sfml

Comment: For g++, you need to tell it where to find the includes by giving it a `-I` option indicating where the headers are.

Comment: i did like that but it return new error :<

Comment: @KaizOffical what is the new error? What c++ compiler do you use to compile your code? Did you use a C++ IDE? Please add more details